# zerodivisionerror-Float division error

Tags: python

```
ctr=0.0
i=0
pc=0.0
pi=0.0
nc=0.0
ni=0.0


for line in fileinput.input(['/pro/file1']):
    line = line.replace("\n", "")
    if (i < len(revs)): 
        if('pos' in revs[i]):
            if(float(line) > 0):
                ctr=ctr+1
                pc=pc+1

            else:
                                pi=pi+1

        elif('neg' in revs[i]):
            if(float(line) < 0):
                ctr=ctr+1
                nc=nc+1

            else:
                                ni=ni+1

    i=i+1
precision = pc/(pc+pi)
recall = pc/(ni+pc)
```

This code is about sentiment analysis.I am getting **ZeroDivisionError:Float division by zero** when I try to find accuracy and recall.how to fix it??

Comment: Don't divide by zero? Where do `revs` come from?

Comment: Maybe you should ask at http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @PavelAnossov revs is a part of coding.here i ve given only the erraneous part!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With no idea if this is a good idea for your case, one way of solving this is to do something like

```
precision = pc/(pc+pi) if (pc+pi) else 0
recall = pc/(ni+pc) if (ni+pc) else 0
```

which will give a zero in the case that there is nothing to divide by. May be what you need, may be horribly hiding a real error.

Edit: If your data makes you take the "neg" branch every time, pc and pi will be zero, so you'll get a div/0 error at

```
precision = pc/(pc+pi)
```

...so that is the *cause*.